# Link error with C++ class and test.cpp and Opencv libs

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm noob in C++ programming but I usually develop in Java.

I'm in a Computer Vision course and we use opencv in C++. We also use Visual Studio v2012.

I've tried to make a Otsu umbralization with a class and a Test cpp file, but I have a link error.

I'm sorry if the problem is basic, but I haven't find any solution:

Preproceso.h

```
#ifndef _H_
#define _H_
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
class Preproceso
{
public:
    Preproceso(void);
    ~Preproceso(void);
    cv::Mat Otsu(cv::Mat imagen);
    cv::Mat HistCalc(cv::Mat imagen);
};
#endif
```

Preproceso.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Preproceso.h"

Preproceso::Preproceso(void)
{
}


Preproceso::~Preproceso(void)
{
}

cv::Mat Otsu(cv::Mat imagen) {
    cv::Mat img_bw;
    cv::threshold(imagen, img_bw, 0, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY | CV_THRESH_OTSU);
    return img_bw;
}

cv::Mat HistCalc(cv::Mat imagen) {
    float rangeColor[] = {0, 256};
    const float* ranges = {rangeColor};
    int channels[] = {0};
    cv::Mat hist;
    int bins = 255;
    int histSize = {bins};

    cv::calcHist(&imagen, 1, channels, cv::Mat(), hist, 1, &bins, &ranges, true, false); 

    return hist;
}
```

Test.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Preproceso.h"

int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Preproceso prep = Preproceso();
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("Crotal1.TIF", 0);
    cv::Mat bw_img = prep.Otsu(image);
    cv::namedWindow( "Otsu", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cv::imshow( "Otsu", bw_img );

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The error is this (in my Spanish version):

> error LNK2019: símbolo externo "public: class cv::Mat __thiscall
>   Preproceso::Otsu(class cv::Mat)"
>   (?umbralizarImage@Preproceso@@QAE?AVMat@cv@@V23@@Z) sin resolver al
>   que se hace referencia en la función _main fatal error LNK1120: 1
>   externos sin resolver

Thanks for the help and sorry for the awful english :(

Comment: did you forget to add "Preproceso.cpp" to your project ? (and again, java would probably have found that on its own, but not c++ ..)

Comment: It's in the Source Code of my project/solution. Preproceso.h is in header foulder.

I've supossed the project has these folder in its path.